# More general continuity of measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Continuity of measure is often referred to as the theorem that states for an increasing or decreasing 
sequence of sets we may exchange limit and measure sign. Are there more general version of this? That is, for some sequence of $A_n$ that satisfies some less restrictive condition, it holds that $\lim_n \mu(A_n)=\mu(\lim_n A_n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$
\mu\left(\liminf_{n\to \infty}A_n\right)\le \liminf_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)\le \limsup_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)\le \mu\left(\limsup_{n\to \infty}A_n\right).
$$
Thus, the result holds if $\liminf_{n\to \infty}A_n=\limsup_{n\to \infty}A_n$.